# Chrome extension high CPU load: how to profile?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have my chrome extension that consists of content script, background page (non-persistent) and browser action. Randomly, it starts to eat CPU like this:

[image]

But how to find what part of my extension is hogging CPU? Is it content script, background page that process some events or javascript code in browser action?

Comment: You didn't share any code, but it's possible that you've created an infinite recursion loop, e.g. by a bad use of the messaging API.

Comment: @RobW Yes, it may be so. I have profiled extension that don't hig CPU and extension that hog CPU (same task runs in a dozen virtual machines, on some of them extension hogs CPU, and on some - not). The only difference is `chrome.Event.removeListener` with 70% CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content scripts run in a tab's process.
Background pages, browser action/page action popups and other extension pages run in the extension's process.

It's likely that your background page is consuming lots of CPU (if the process still hogs CPU after closing the pop-up). To find the cause, [open the developer tools for the background page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029/938089?where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension), and start [profiling](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/profiles) (see [CPU profiling](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. May i ask a few more questions about correct profiling before accepting your answer? :)

Comment: @EyeofHell The CPU profiling feature is quite straightforward, so I think that you'll manage it after reading the documentation (mostly pictures with a few lines of explanation). If you get stuck, feel free to ask a follow-up question.

Comment: Thanks again. Am i correct that in order to profile `background page` i need to select `Tools`->`Extensions`, click `generate background page` and use `Profiles` tab?